# Is has and belongs to many suitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

Am new to this site, looking forward to getting more involved :)

I'm creating a customer ordering system using rails3, devise, cancan etc.

In brief, we three models:

1. Users
2. Companies
3. Orders

I'm struggling to understand the relationships though. Initially the users had many companies and the companies belonged to a user.

However, we actually have two sorts of user:

1. The admin staff here who can create companies, update details etc.
2. Our customers who can login and see only their companies and related orders.

I thought about creating two controllers - admin and users but it seems unnecessary and not very rails. Plus cancan can do all that I think.

What do you think we should do here? We were thinking about using the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship but most people online seem to say avoid it.

Thanks,

Jenny

--- edit ---

Thanks to all of you who've helped!

After some reading, I decided to use the has many through association.

I created a new model called agreement and set my models up as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agreements
  has_many :companies, :through => :agreements
end


class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agreements
  has_many :users, :through => :agreements
end
```

I'm a little stuck though and can't find a good example online.

Should I be creating a user and company separately and then create an agreement to match the two up?

Again, thanks for the help All.

Comment: have you found a working solution now? if yes, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the description it sounds like you have:

1. Users
2. Customers
3. Companies
4. Orders

The Admins are Users who have the role allowing them access to the create,update on the companies.  A customer belongs to a company and may also be a 'user' depending on the information you store in the User model.

As for the HABTM it's still ok to use if you aren't putting additional data within the join table.  Typically though you'll have some information in the join table since it provides additional context to the join.

A nice resource for sample data models, and to give some ideas around the Entities and relationships is [Library of Free Data Models](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/)

Comment: That's the gist of it. Thanks, I will read through the library.. J

Comment: I agree that you may benefit from another model.  Perhaps you could have an Admin model with a record for each user that needed admin permissions.  Like others above, I prefer to use has_many :through.

Comment: Thanks, just edited my first question. Think the has_many through is best. Have set up but am now a bit stuck!!

Answer (score 0):

You can go with has_many :through .As it seems application will surely need some continuous changes in the coming future.So in this case it will be helpful
Reply if any queries

Thanx

Comment: Hi, thanks. If users have many companies and companies have many users how do I use 'through' - they seem to be directly connected? JB

Comment: @jenny  you can directly use,also it helps if you want to increase any attributes..http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html .Have a look it will make you clear

Comment: sorry, new to all this?! Is that right??! Am going to try to use a has_many :through association. Still a bit stuck though, made some comments in original. J

Comment: class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end                                                                   I think this is what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know what you really want to achieve, understand the relationships and how the relationship needs to look like. Draw some entity relationship model on paper, that helps.

Personally, I prefer to user has_many :through because if you need to store additional data for that relation (which may be the case when extening your app) you're already set and don't need to migrate your tables and models from habtm to has_many :through.

For the user permissions, stick to cancan.

Comment: Hi, habtm seems to work but I don't really want a join table with the company information in... Looks right, but has_many through seems tidier. Just not really sure how it will work in my scenario.. J